# How to set animation to pop the pushed UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller

I have a litle problem. I have a pushviewcontroller and it uses an animation.
My code is like this:

```
   [UIView  beginAnimations: @"Showinfo"context: nil];
   [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:dtv  animated:YES];
   [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
   [UIView commitAnimations];`
```

It works good, but when the `view` is pushed and I go back, this doesn't do the animation.
So I don't know how to do the same animation when I go back.
can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: what you are actually trying to do through this?

Comment: just push a new viewcontroller, but with an animation. And I want when I go back, the view do the same animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I've always managed to complete this task.

For Push:

```
[UIView  beginAnimations: @"Showinfo"context: nil];
   [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:dtv  animated:YES];
   [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
   [UIView commitAnimations];`
```

For Pop:

[

```
UIView  beginAnimations: @"Showinfo"context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.375];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I still get a lot of feedback from this so I'm going to go ahead and update it to use animation blocks which is the Apple recommended way to do animations anyway.

For Push:

```
MainView *nextView = [[MainView alloc] init];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                         animations:^{
                             [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                             [super pushViewController:nextView animated:NO];
                             [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                         }];
```

For Pop:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                         animations:^{
                             [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                             [UIView setAnimationTransition:transition forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                         }];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternate, you can use this also,

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
//transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```